# What is the purpose of an anonymous JavaScript function wrapped in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, idioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Why the anonymous function wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643321/javascript-why-the-anonymous-function-wrapper)

I read the code of some JavaScript libraries, and found in some js files there are such statements:

```
;(function(){

})();
```

I've got a few questions :

1. What the code does?
2. Why the code is designed in such way?
3. How to invoke functions defined in the code?