# standalone parentheses in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [JavaScript: Why the anonymous function wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643321/javascript-why-the-anonymous-function-wrapper)
>   [A Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340874/a-javascript-function)
>   [How does the (function() {})() construct work and why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639180/how-does-the-function-construct-work-and-why-do-people-use-it)

I saw some code in javascript in following format :

```
(
 function()
 {
   //stmt
 }
)();
```

Why exactly do we use these standalone parentheses? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This code creates a function expression, then calls it immediately.

It's the same as

```
var unnamed = function() { ... };

(unnamed) ();
```

Answer (score 1):

The last two parantheses before the `;` execute the anonymous function directly. The other two parantheses are optional and just some sort of convention.

This pattern is commonly used for not polluting the global namespace:

```
(function() {
  var a = 42;
})();

alert(a); // a is undefined
```

Paul Irish has a pretty good screencast about this and other javascript patterns: http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/

Answer (score 1):

This is the basis for what is called the Module pattern in Javascript. See these articles for more information:

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Essentially, as the articles state, this pattern is perfect for maintaining privacy and state, but also allow loose coupling and chaining of your Javascript modules.

Comment: The example in the OP is not the module pattern, it is a simple anonymous function expression that is immediately executed. It would only be the module pattern if it actually created an object with methods accessible outside of the anonymous function - typically done by returning said object though there are other ways. But there are other, non-module reasons why you might wrap some code in an anonymous immediately executed function, e.g., to create some temporary working variables for a particular calculation without polluting the global namespace.

Comment: I still liked the resources. They are good.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Agreed, it is not a pattern but a basis for a pattern. I have edited my post accordingly. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The standalone parentheses `()` means to execute the function, in this code, it's a anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Creates annonymous function and calls it, therefore avoiding pollution of the namespace and memory for functions that are called only once.

Although similar to:

```
var f = function () { ... };
f();
```

This variant avoids creating a variable f, which saves memory and avoids namespace conflicts.